# Microsoft Excel - Copy Pasting while maintaining reference to a single cell

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-office, microsoft-excel-2007

Let's say that I have a value in cell A5 that is being used to calculate a value in A3.

Example:

```
A3 = (A1 + A2) * A5
```

When I copy paste cells A1:A3 and paste onto B1:B3, I'd like the resulting formula to be this:

```
B3 = (B1 + B2) * A5
```

Notice that A5 is still there.

It is the default behavior of Excel to cause this to be B5 instead of A5.

Is there a way to force a reference a single cell, such as A5, to be maintained while copy pasting rows?

Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You want to use [Absolute References](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/relative.aspx) then instead of relative references.  Yes that is the default behavior of Excel.  In your example do $A$5 to always reference A5.

```
A3 = (A1 + A2) * $A$5
B3 = (B1 + B2) * $A$5
```

Comment: To quickly turn an "A5" into a "$A$5" press "F4". This will help you scroll through fixed references: $A5 (Column fixed); A$5 (Row fixed); $A$5 (Column&Row fixed)

Answer (score 2):

In the formula, instead of referencing A5, reference $A$5. You can also keep only the column, but with changing row numbers, through referencing $A5, or only keep the column, changing row, by referencing A$5.