# Not using a cell as variable, whilst inserting a (excel-)formula in several cells

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, cells

I'm facing a small, basic little problem, for which I can't find the solution: 
I'd like to insert the same formula in several cells at once. Quickly googling this problem provides a solution: 
Either highlighting all cells and use *ctrl+enter*, or using the *fill* tool. But all of these solutions change the formula accordingly. (e.g. if I use *=P1/12*, and select all cells from *B1* to *O1*, *P1* decrements) The cell should not be treated as a variable.

Basically, I just want to type in a number (e.g. expenses) for one year, that gets split up in 12 equal numbers for each month, hence *P1/12*.

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but absolute reference rather than relative doesn't work (i.e. $P$1/12)?

Comment: @BillDOe Didn't know about this, I am an absolute beginner. I guess I should have followed the tutorial a little longer. :)

Comment: Okay, @BlueGI provided the same answer, which I see you've accepted.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Microsoft Excel applies formula wrongly](https://superuser.com/questions/428632/microsoft-excel-applies-formula-wrongly)

Comment: See also [Can’t get the formula to autofill correctly](https://superuser.com/q/633623/150988)  and [Copy Pasting while maintaining reference to a single cell](https://superuser.com/q/164418/150988).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use $ in front of each part of the cell to keep it static.
For example: =$P$1/12

Comment: `$` is what keeps a reference absolute, `$A$1`, `A$1` and `$A1` are all acceptable uses

Comment: @cybernetic.nomad Thanks for the additional information